# How to add a new database on replication?

Tags: mysql, database, replication, mariadb

I have a mysql replication with two servers.
There are actually 3 databases on it.

On master :

```
server-id               = 1
log_bin                 = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days        = 4
max_binlog_size         = 1G
bind-address            = 0.0.0.0
port                    = 3306

binlog_do_db            = database1
binlog_do_db            = database2
binlog_do_db            = database3
```

And on slave:

```
server-id               = 2
log_bin                 = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days        = 4
max_binlog_size         = 1G
bind-address            = 127.0.0.1
port                    = 3306

replicate_do_db            = database1
replicate_do_db            = database2
replicate_do_db            = database3
```

But i need to add a new one, database4.
Do I have to stop servers for this ?
By simply adding the base in the cnf file, can this be taken into account dynamically?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to ask the Primary to send a database that it has not always been configured to send.  So...

Plan A:  Add the rows to configs *before* creating the database.  Yes, a restart of each is needed.

Plan B (you already have the database on the Primary):

1. stop writing to the Primary
2. Dump db4
3. update both config files
4. Load the dump on Replica
5. Restart both

Notes on config:

- If you have no binlog/replica_do/ignore configuration, all will be replicated.
- binlog_do says what to send out from the Primary; replicate_do says what to allow into the Replica.  That is, they have the same effect.  (The settings become useful when only some Replicas need to receive the data.)